# Call function with HTML inside tags

Tags: php, html, function

I'm new to PHP and recently discovered another way of doing 'if statements' to make integration with large amounts of HTML easier:

```
<?php if(something): ?>

All the HTML in here

<?php endif; ?>
```

Now I'm wondering if a similar thing can be done with functions? I've declared a function that creates some variables and now I want to call that function and use those variables in parts of my HTML.

E.g.

```
function test(){
  $test1 = 'test1';
  $test2 = 'test2';
}

test();
<div><?php $test1; ?></div>
<div><?php $test2; ?></div>
```

The above won't work because the variables created in the function are not global and I don't want to make them global. The function is declared in a separate php file.

My initial searches didn't turn up anything for this.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to make them global?

Comment: if you dont want to make the variables global, you need to return them, there is no other way for them to get out of the function. but from your code, it seems like global would be the best approach

Comment: make function return value and then do <div><?php ECHO test();?></div>

Comment: My recent research into PHP variables has suggested that global variables aren't a good idea. Also, I only need these variables for this one isolated part, so if there's another option, there's no point making them global.

Comment: Well we told you for another option. If  you don't understand what we mean, I can make it in answer with example, but really best way to learn is to try yourself.

Comment: @Dexa my previous comment was aimed at the first two comments. I'm looking into using returns from variables now. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ummm.. Using an array?

```
function test(){
  $result = array(); // Empty array
  $result['test1'] = 'test1';
  $result['test2'] = 'test2';
  return $result; // Return the array
}

$result = test(); // Get the resulting array
<div><?php $result['test1']; ?></div>
<div><?php $result['test2']; ?></div>
```

Or you could do it in kinda objective-y way:

```
function test(){
  $result = new stdClass; // Empty object
  $result->test1 = 'test1';
  $result->test2 = 'test2';
  return $result; // Return the object
}

$result = test(); // Get the resulting object
<div><?php $result->test1; ?></div>
<div><?php $result->test2; ?></div>
```

Comment: Yep this is the stuff.

Answer (score 1):

You can use them if you `return;` them. Check 
http://php.net/manual/en/function.return.php for more details of the `return;` sintax.